# Best way to define an information array with a class

Tags: php, arrays, types, mapping, project

I have a database table which stores a "type" for a project which stores either a 1, 2 or 3 where:

1 = "Active"
2 = "Inactive"
3 = "Cancelled"

Currently, I store this mapping in an array in my config.php making it a global variable accessible from my whole application. It looks something like:

```
$project_types = array(1 => "Active", 2 => "Inactive", 3 => "Cancelled");
```

Now, I have a Project class, which has get_type() and set_type() methods to alter the integer value as expected.
I want to have a get_type_name() method. Can anyone here explain what this method should look like? Currently, I have something that looks like this:

```
public function get_type_name() {
    global $project_types;
    return $project_types[$this->get_type()];
}
```

I the array above should somehow lay inside my Project class, but I'm just not sure what route to take.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it will just work, you simply put this `get_type_name` function in the `Project` class and it should give you its type name when you invoke it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Globals are bad, and in your case, creates an unnecessary dependency for your Project class.

The solution (one of many) is quite simple:
Create a class property that holds the types and do the lookup on it.

```
class Project {

    /**
     * @param array Holds human translations of project types.
     */
    protected $_types = array(
        1 => 'Active',
        2 => 'Inactive',
        3 => 'Cancelled',
    );

    /**
     * Get a human-readable translation of the project's current type.
     *
     * If a translation can't be found, it returns NULL.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function get_human_type() {
        $type = $this->get_type();
        return isset($this->_types[$type]) ? $this->_types[$type] : NULL;
    }

}
```

Comment: Also, you are much better off sticking to the Zend Coding standards... ie. method and property names should be in camel case and private/public methods and properties prepended with an `_`

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I'd declare it as a static class property, possibly using class constants for the different values:

```
class Project
{
    /**    constants */
    const STATUS_ACTIVE         = 'Active';
    const STATUS_INACTIVE       = 'Inactive';
    const STATUS_CANCELLED      = 'Cancelled';

    protected static $projectTypes    = array( 1 => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
                                               2 => self::STATUS_INACTIVE,
                                               3 => self::STATUS_CANCELLED
                                             );

    public function getTypeName() {
        return self::$projectTypes[$this->get_type()];
    } 

}
```

These constants can be accessed using

> self::STATUS_ACTIVE

from within the class, or

> Project::STATUS_ACTIVE

from outside;

and the array can be accessed using

> self::$project_types

Comment: And what about the get_type_name() method?

self::$project_types - I think that's what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @Justin - just added it to the Project class (assuming that this is indeed the name of your project class)